# "while running the android game app" gives warning message in logcat

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

To learn the implementation process of game apps, so had imported the game project but when i run the project i get this error message in logcat "No Launcher activity found! The launch will only sync the application package on the device!" even edited my manifeast but still din get the output"
Manifeast.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jamescho.androidgame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No Launcher activity found!

Declare activity as Launcher which is open initially when application start and declare all activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ActitityName" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: but now app gets force close i had pasted the logtrace above @TGMCians

Comment: @DD. I checked the logcat. Here in my above answer. I gave the activity android:name=".ActitityName". It just a example. You need to modify the activity name whatever in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Declare activity as Launcher which is open initially when application start and declare all activity in AndroidManifest.xml